# How to access monitoring web UI when running spark on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, monitoring

I'm running spark from AWS EC2. As the spark documentation said

> "Each driver program has a web UI, typically on port 4040, that displays information about running tasks, executors, and storage usage. Simply go to http://:4040 in a web browser to access this UI"

My question is: what is this "driver-node"? 
I thought it's the public IP of the driver node xx.xx.xxx.xx. But I kept getting page not found error when I user http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:4040

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to create a security group and assign to it and open the inbound port such as 0.0.0.0/0 with port 4040

Then you should be fine to access it with its public IP, such as:

```
http://54.xx.xx.xx:4040
```

0.0.0.0/0 is opened to all, you can change it to your own IP or other ip ranges to limit the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question as you. Eventually, the  should be replaced by your IP address.

But not the IP address after you google "what's my IP address". You should execute ipconfig in command line and use that IP address in the URL.

And if you don't have a valid sparkContext (sc) running, the UI will return error

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

1. ssh tunnel to the remote/ec2 port, e.g.,

   ```
   ssh -i "c:\path\to\keypair.pem" -N -L \
     4040:ec2-##-###-###-##.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4040 \
     ec2-user@ec2-##-###-###-##.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
   ```
2. Then just connect your browser to http://localhost:4040/